# Data pagination for div content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pagination

Guys please I need your help, I'm just starting with my programming journey. I've written a code for e-commerce website, where I have div row containing 4 columns each as div column hold the data for each item. Now I'm sure the rows will be much to have enough items on the site but I need it to show 10 or 12 items at a time. I haven't write anything about the pagination because my JavaScript knowledge is close to non. Please I need your help guys

Comment: Are you using javascript on the server (NodeJS) ? or inside the browser (where you use JQuery) ?

Comment: Just inside the browser raxi

Comment: Pagination is almost always done server side, as the reason for pagination is generally that there is too much information to send it all to the client at once. Because of that, pagination generally isn't accomplished by javascript in the browser.

Comment: One way javascript can play a role in pagination, is that some websites use ajax (http requests inside javascript) to request a certain slice of the data (like say "get the data for product#400 up to product#420") and then update the page with that. But in that situation the pagination is still happening serverside. -- I'm not sure if there is a serverside scripting language involved in your situation. Some people use javascript for that (NodeJS), others PHP or one of many other alternatives.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ It looks as though you're trying to get someone to write code for you which is not what this website is for _ Please add any code attempt that you've tried. You should also visit SO Help Center 'Asking' section to find out more about submitting a properly formatted question _ Doing this will help to ensure that your posts don't receive negative points >>> stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

One approach for you to consider is using libraries such as [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). It has html table pagination enabled but you need to familiarize yourself with it.

Comment: I don't know if it's a good idea to use table, because I have item name, image, item details button, buy button, price and badge that shows reduction in normal price. A div is the best thing to arrange all these things neatly for me

Comment: you can take a look at its examples, it supports button, pagination, sorting, search, filtering, etc